# Unable to get any HTML code from site with jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm new in the forum. 
I can't find a serious programming support site in my country, so i'll try my luck here.
I'm having problems getting HTML source code from a precise site:http://www.meteoam.it/ta/previsione/110/magenta

I'm using this code:

```
  Document document2 =Jsoup.connect("http://www.meteoam.it/ta/previsione/110/magenta").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").get();
                            Elements temp2 = document2.select("div.tab-content");
                            html = "";
                            i = 0;
                            for (Element movielist : temp2) {
                                i++;
                                html = (i + "|||" + movielist.getElementsByTag("td").html());
                                array3b[i] = html;
                            }
```

I'd like to get temperature infos so between:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<tr>INFO</tr>
<div>
```

Strange thing is that I'm not able to get any code from this website. 
Can somebody help me at least verifying if this site has a sort of protection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `document2` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting too many table cells. The values you want are there but difficult to find. You can create better CSS selector to match only table cells you want. Try this code. Explanation in comments:

```
        Document document2 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.meteoam.it/ta/previsione/110/magenta")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").get();
        /* after analyzing HTML of this page I see we can find table by id "oggi" and get all TD cells */
        Elements tableCells = document2.select("div#oggi td");
        /* I see you want to keep the values in an array so I'm creating
           an array of the size matching amount of table cells found */
        String[] values = new String[tableCells.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Element td : tableCells) {
            /* putting each cell text into the array */
            values[i++] = td.text();
        }
        /* display collected values */
        System.out.println("TEMP " + values[2]);
        System.out.println("UMIDITÀ " + values[3]);
        System.out.println("VENTO " + values[4]);
        System.out.println("RAFFICHE " + values[5]);
```

Comment: many thanks for the kind answer, but that code doesn't work too. I'm getting a null array :(

Comment: both values[i] and document2.html() are absolutely empty. I'm sure the problem is not in the code because by changing only the url I'm able to get data. Actually till now I wasn't able to get any data at all from this website.

Comment: Strange. It worked yesterday and works today, current output is `TEMP 21 UMIDITÀ 65 VENTO 3 RAFFICHE 7`

Comment: Sorry. i got the exception error just now: java.io.ioexception cleartext http traffic to www.meteoam.it not permitted, just after document2=..

Comment: i added : android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to te Manifest.xml and now it works